# .htaccess 500 internal server error when routing api

Tags: reactjs, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently running php on an apache server locally, with a React frontend.

This is how my current `.htaccess` is laid out:

```
Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ api/$1\.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api.*?
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

The bottom condition is so that routing works in my React app. I'm then taking the production build and copying it into my htdocs.

The routing works, however, I want to be able to call the .php files inside my `/api` directory **without using the file extension**. So I want anything that comes after `/api/` to be redirected to whatever is entered, followed by `.php`.

E.g. `/api/authentication` would go to `/api/authentication.php`, and `/api/register` would go to `/api/register.php`, and so on.

With this current setup, I'm getting a 500 internal server error when making requests to `/api/authentication` etc.

Is there something wrong with my `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Please set `APP_DEBUG=true` in the `.env` file and check for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first rule is looping as you're matching `.*`. You may use:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^api/(.+)$ api/$1.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^api index.html [L,NC]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]` will skip rewriting when a URI ends with `.php`.

Comment: Nothing loads using this solution. Just blank pages.

Comment: Emptied cache and hard reloaded, checked network tab with no 404 errors and yet I still get blank pages.

Comment: No I do not, those are in a /static folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221641/discussion-between-anubhava-and-theperplexedone).